# Rotate a multipolygon without changing the inner spatial relation

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, multipolygons

I have a multipolygon shapefile that i want to rotate. I can do the rotation but the problem is that the roatation changes the inner vertices. This creates overlap of polygon which i dont want.

This is what i have tried.

```
import geopandas as gpd
input_poly_path = "poly3.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(input_poly_path)
explode = gdf.explode(ignore_index=True)
ex = explode.rotate(-90, origin="centroid")
g = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry'], geometry='geometry')
g["geometry"] = ex
```

[image: Original polygon]
[image: Rotated polygon]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HJpnNL-iXU_rReQzVcDGuyWZ8IjciKP8?usp=drive_link
Link to the polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you need to pass the [`centroid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html#shapely.Polygon.centroid) of the [`unary_union`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.unary_union.html) as the *origin* of the rotation :

```
out = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=gdf.rotate(
        angle=-90, origin=list(gdf.unary_union.centroid.coords)[0]
    )
)
```

***NB**: There is no need to [`explode`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html#) the geometry, because you do not have [MultiPolygons](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.MultiPolygon.html).*

[image]

Used input (`gdf`) :

```
import geopandas as gpd

# download from Google Drive
input_poly_path = (
    "C:/Users/Timeless/Downloads/"
    "share-20240330T125957Z-001.zip!share"
)

gdf = gpd.read_file(input_poly_path, engine="pyogrio")
```

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking in the same directions, but was unsure as three polygon can share a common vertices and the other will not, and we  have to rotate each polygon as they are not one entity. It would helpful if you could clarify how did it work.

Comment: You're welcome.  In your approach, we use a different centroid/origin to rotate the four polygons, i.e, each one is moving **independently**. In mine, we compute a single centroid of all the polygons as a whole (*hence, the union*) to ensure they all rotate `-90` degrees **simultaneously**. *see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ubiD.png)*.

Comment: Okay, i was thinking that we cannot rotate a polygon with  the origin cordinate outside the boundary of that polygon. Thanks once again.